# PHP script to upload a file to a FTP

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp

I would like to a file `MYFILE.csv` to a remote FTP. Below is the script. The connection part works but not the file upload. I get the "There was a problem while uploading" message.

Thank you for your help.

```
<?php
$server = 'ftp.website.com' ;//Address of ftp server
$user_name = 'MYUSERNAME'; // Username
$password = 'MYPASSWORD'; // Password

$source_file = '/home/MYFILES.csv'; 
$dest = '/in/';

// set up basic connection
$connection = ftp_connect($server, 21) or die("Couldn't connect to     $ftp_server"); 

echo "can connect";
echo "<br />";
// login with username and password
ftp_login($connection, $user_name, $password) or die("Cannot login");
echo "can login";
echo "<br />";

  // upload a file
  if (ftp_put($connection, $dest, $source_file, FTP_BINARY)) 
 { echo "successfully uploaded \n";} 
  else
  { echo "There was a problem while uploading \n";}

// close the connection
ftp_close($connection);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

```
?php
$server = 'ftp.WEBSITE.com' ;//Address of ftp server
$user_name = 'MYUSERNAME'; // Username
$password = 'MYPASSWORD'; // Password

$source_file = '/home/MYFILE.csv'; 
$dest = '/in/MYFILE.csv';

// set up basic connection 
$connection = ftp_connect($server, 21) or die("Couldn't connect to     $ftp_server"); 
echo "can connect";
 echo "<br />";

// login with username and password
ftp_login($connection, $user_name, $password) or die("Cannot login");
echo "can login";
echo "<br />";
// upload a file
ftp_put($connection, $dest, $source_file, FTP_ASCII) or die ("Cannot upload");

// close the connection
    ftp_close($connection);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i see the dest folder is "/in/".

Are you sure that its not trying to put it at the root folder of your ftp ?
(Which may belongs to root user, that's would be why it fail)